# TwitterAPIExchange 'couldn't connect to host'

Tags: php, twitter

I'm trying to search twitter using [TwitterAPIExchange](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php) but it 
gives the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'couldn't    
connect to host' in [...]/TwitterAPIExchange.php:305 Stack trace: #0 
[...]/tweet.php(19): TwitterAPIExchange->performRequest() #1 {main} thrown 
in [...]/teamwatch/TwitterAPIExchange.php on line 305
```

At this stage i really don't care about MITM attacks so I've followed the suggestions found in other stackoverflow questions and added the curl option
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, but the result not changed.

So I don't understand what's wrong with my script.

```
<?php
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "*****************",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "*****************",
    'consumer_key' => "*****************",
    'consumer_secret' => "*****************"
);

$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$getfield = '?q=%40twitterapi';
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$options = array( CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false );

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
echo $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
    ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
    ->performRequest(true, $options);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the lack of curlCSS on the hosting... the code is fine.